# Same name under different class, get URL, BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, html, url, beautifulsoup

I have this HTML, and  I need to get the URLs on it:

```
<div class="posts-container col-md-6"
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list"
     <a class="entry-title" href="commonlink.com"
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list"
     <a class="entry-title" href="rarelink.com"

<div class="col-md-6"
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list"
     <a class="entry-title" href="anothercommonlink.com"
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list"
     <a class="entry-title" href="legendarylink.com"
```

When I apply:

```
for i in soup.findAll('div', "posts-container col-md-6"):
    for anchor in soup.findAll('a', class_="entry-title", href=True):
        print(anchor['href'])
```

I get:

```
>commonlink.com
>rarelink.com
>anothercommonlink.com
>legendarylink.com
```

I only want to get the "posts-container col-md-6" ones:

```
>commonlink.com
>rarelink.com
```

Comment: Iterate over ``i`` in the inner loop instead of the complete page ``for anchor in i.findAll('a', class_="entry-title", href=True)``.

Comment: @Sushanth For  some reason it only returns "Process finished with exit code 0" that way :/

Answer (score 0):

To get all links under `<div>` with `class="posts-container col-md-6"` use CSS selector `.posts-container.col-md-6 a`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<div class="posts-container col-md-6">
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list">
     <a class="entry-title" href="commonlink.com">some link1</a>
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list">
     <a class="entry-title" href="rarelink.com">some link2</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list">
     <a class="entry-title" href="anothercommonlink.com">some link3</a>
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list">
     <a class="entry-title" href="legendarylink.com">some link4</a>
</div>'''



soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('.posts-container.col-md-6 a'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
commonlink.com
rarelink.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''
<div class="posts-container col-md-6">
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list">
     <a class="entry-title" href="commonlink.com">some link1</a>
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list">
     <a class="entry-title" href="rarelink.com">some link2</a>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list">
     <a class="entry-title" href="anothercommonlink.com">some link3</a>
   <ul class="emb-embassies-list">
     <a class="entry-title" href="legendarylink.com">some link4</a>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
ancors = soup.find('div', class_="posts-container col-md-6").find_all('a')

for a in ancors:
    print(a['href'])
```

Output will be:

```
commonlink.com
rarelink.com
```